# Linear programming word problem

Tags: linear-programming, word-problem

A sports event for a school has 300 tickets. They'll sell tickets to students for $5$ dollars and to teachers for $6$ dollars. School rules say that there must be at least $1$ teacher for every $5$ students on the trip. The school also wants to have at least twice as many students as teachers on the trip. There are $110$ seats on the school-bus that ticketholders must use to ride to the event. Each seat can fit either 2 teachers or 3 students. To how many teachers should the school sell tickets to maximize revenue (and such that all ticketholders fit on the bus)?

Let $x=$ number of students and $y=$ number of teachers, objective function: $5x+6y$

Constraints:

$x+y\leq300$

$5y\geq x$

$x\geq2y$

$\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{2}y\leq110$

Maximum: $5x+6y=1560$ at $(240,60)$ hence teachers: $60$

Can anyone check if my work is correct or not?

Comment: No @Anvit, $5y \ge x$ is correct.  For example, $x \ge 5$ implies $y \ge 1$.  Also, linear programming does not allow strict inequalities, anyway.

Comment: @RobPratt I see my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, although you might want to explicitly impose lower bounds $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.  The dual variables $(3,0,0,6)$ provide a short proof that $1560$ is an upper bound on the objective value:
$$5x+6y = 3(x+y)+6\left(\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{2}y\right) \le 3(300) + 6(110) = 1560$$